# jquery help with css() and animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-animate, dom-events

I have this nav system,

```
<nav id="mainnav">
    <ul>
        <li<?php if ( $this->uri->segment(1) == '' ): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>><a href="">Jobwall</a></li>
        <li<?php if ( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'jobfeed' ): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>><a href="">Live Job Feed</a></li>
        <li<?php if ( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'tutorials' ): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>><a href="">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li<?php if ( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'services' ): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>><a href="">Employer Services</a></li>
    </ul>
    <section id="progress"></section>
</nav>
```

based on the uri the li gets an active class, and based on that active a background image moves to show which page is active, however this only works when I use the CSS function jquery link so,

```
if($("#mainnav li:eq(0)").hasClass('active'))
{
    $("#progress").css({backgroundPosition: '-883px 0px'})
} 

if($("#mainnav li:eq(1)").hasClass('active'))
{
    alert("hello");
    $("#progress").css({backgroundPosition: '-783px 0px'})
}

if($("#mainnav li:eq(2)").hasClass('active'))
{
    $("#progress").css({backgroundPosition: '-702px 0px'})
}

if($("#mainnav li:eq(3)").hasClass('active'))
{
    $("#progress").css({backgroundPosition: '-567px 0px'})
}
```

If I use,

```
if($("#mainnav li:eq(0)").hasClass('active'))
{
    $("#progress").animate({backgroundPosition: '-883px 0px'})
} 

if($("#mainnav li:eq(1)").hasClass('active'))
{
    alert("hello");
    $("#progress").animate({backgroundPosition: '-783px 0px'})
}

if($("#mainnav li:eq(2)").hasClass('active'))
{
    $("#progress").animate({backgroundPosition: '-702px 0px'})
}

if($("#mainnav li:eq(3)").hasClass('active'))
{
    $("#progress").animate({backgroundPosition: '-567px 0px'})
}
```

then nothing happens and my `background-position` is `0px 0px` why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-position isn't built into jQuery's core animate functionality.  You can add it with background-position plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

Answer (score 1):

For each of these lines change `backgroundPosition` to `'background-position'`, for example:

```
$("#progress").css({'background-position': '-883px 0px'});
```